# Inserting an array in Chart.JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I get all the values of expirationdate and price in the loop. How do I write them to a variable and how do I specify them in `labels: [],data: []`?

```
success: function (data) {
            if (data.result) {
                for (let i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
                    console.log(data.result[i].expirationdate);
                    console.log(data.result[i].price);

                }
                var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
                    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: {
                             labels: [],
                            datasets: [{
                                label: 'Payment',
                                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                data: [],
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {}
                    });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you want the `expirationdate` to fill the `labels` property, and `price` to fill the `data` property? If not, please edit your question to better explain.

Comment: I want to insert data.result[i].expirationdate in labels: [] and data.result[i]. price in data: []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
    success: function (data) {
                if (data.result) {
                    var expirationdates = [];
                    var prices = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
                        labels.push(data.result[i].expirationdate);
                        prices.push(data.result[i].price);
                    }
                    
                    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
                    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: {
                             labels: expirationdates,
                            datasets: [{
                                label: 'Payment',
                                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                data: prices,
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {}
                    });
                }
            }
```

However, I can't test it without an example of the `data` object.

Comment: Edited to make the assignment much clearer.